# Automatic pausing of video with media9?

Tags: beamer, media9, multimedia

Is there a way I can pause an embedded beamer video at some specified time point?

Video Playing Code (media9):

```
\includemedia[
width=\textwidth,height=0.5625\textwidth,
addresource=video.mp4, 
flashvars={
source=video.mp4
&loop=true 
&scaleMode=letterbox 
}
]{}{VPlayer.swf}
```

I can probably split the video into two, have the first half play, then play the second half on click. But I am wondering if there is an easier solution?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can insert a custom play button which also starts a (JavaScript-) timer to pause the video after a given time-out. In the example below, the video pauses 10 s after the play button has been pressed.

`playPause` and `pause` are ActionScript functions of `VPlayer.swf` which are exposed to the JavaScript engine of Adobe Reader. There are two ways of calling them from within `\mediabutton`s, either via the `mediacommand` option or in a `jsaction` script, passed as argument to the `callAS` (=call ActionScript) method of the `AnnotRichMedia` object.

```
\includemedia[
  label=myvideo,
  width=\textwidth,height=0.5625\textwidth,
  addresource=video.mp4, 
  flashvars={
    source=video.mp4
%    loop % disabled 
    &scaleMode=letterbox 
  }
]{}{VPlayer.swf}

\mediabutton[
  mediacommand=myvideo:playPause,
  jsaction=myvideo:{
    try{app.clearTimeOut(tout)}catch(e){} % kill pending timers
    var tout=app.setTimeOut('annotRM.myvideo.callAS("pause")', 10000);
  }
]{\fbox{Play/Pause}}
```

Comment: Ah, if only I knew this last week :)